# Extracting quoted and labelled data from a given column

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics, table

I have a large [GTF file](http://mblab.wustl.edu/GTF22.html), like below:

```
 # ./stringtie -p 4 -G /home/humangenome_hg19/homo_gtf_file.gtf -o strAD1_as/transcripts.gtf -l strAD1 /home/software/star-2.5.2b/bin/Linux_x86_64/mapA1Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam                               
# StringTie version 1.3.2d                              
1   StringTie   transcript  30267   31109   1000    +   .   gene_id "strAD1.1"; transcript_id "strAD1.1.1"; reference_id "ENST00000469289"; ref_gene_id "ENSG00000243485"; ref_gene_name "MIR1302-10"; cov "0.028725"; FPKM "0.053510"; TPM "0.109957";
1   StringTie   exon    30267   30667   1000    +   .   gene_id "strAD1.1"; transcript_id "strAD1.1.1"; exon_number "1"; reference_id "ENST00000469289"; ref_gene_id "ENSG00000243485"; ref_gene_name "MIR1302-10"; cov "0.014218";
1   StringTie   exon    30976   31109   1000    +   .   gene_id "strAD1.1"; transcript_id "strAD1.1.1"; exon_number "2"; reference_id "ENST00000469289"; ref_gene_id "ENSG00000243485"; ref_gene_name "MIR1302-10"; cov "0.072139";
```

I want to have the 9th column with just `gene_id`, `transcript_id`, `reference_id` and `ref_gene_id`. They are in the 9th column and separated by space (the columns themselves are TAB-separated). Could you please help me out how I can such a column with a simple command in Linux? I don't want to use Excel for it.

Comment: The rest of the column are delimited by tabs?

Comment: Yes, they are delimited by tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, since the data is in GTF format, one should use a GTF parser to parse it.  I currently have no such parser or parsing library installed so my solution is based solely on the data that you have provided in the question.

To extract the 9th column:

```
$ cut -f 9 data.gtf
gene_id "strAD1.1"; transcript_id "strAD1.1.1"; reference_id "ENST00000469289"; ref_gene_id "ENSG00000243485"; ref_gene_name "MIR1302-10"; cov "0.028725"; FPKM "0.053510"; TPM "0.109957";
gene_id "strAD1.1"; transcript_id "strAD1.1.1"; exon_number "1"; reference_id "ENST00000469289"; ref_gene_id "ENSG00000243485"; ref_gene_name "MIR1302-10"; cov "0.014218";
gene_id "strAD1.1"; transcript_id "strAD1.1.1"; exon_number "2"; reference_id "ENST00000469289"; ref_gene_id "ENSG00000243485"; ref_gene_name "MIR1302-10"; cov "0.072139";
```

To get the data that we want from this, we need to treat transcripts and exons separately as their attributes have different order in the data. We do this with `awk` and output different fields in the input data depending on whether the current line contains the string `exon_number` or not:

```
$ cut -f 9 data.gtf | awk '/exon_number/ { print $2, $4, $8, $10; next } { print $2, $4, $6, $8 }'
"strAD1.1"; "strAD1.1.1"; "ENST00000469289"; "ENSG00000243485";
"strAD1.1"; "strAD1.1.1"; "ENST00000469289"; "ENSG00000243485";
"strAD1.1"; "strAD1.1.1"; "ENST00000469289"; "ENSG00000243485";
```

Then we remove the double quotes and semicolons from this:

```
$ cut -f 9 data.gtf | awk '/exon_number/ { print $2, $4, $8, $10; next } { print $2, $4, $6, $8 }' | tr -d '";'
strAD1.1 strAD1.1.1 ENST00000469289 ENSG00000243485
strAD1.1 strAD1.1.1 ENST00000469289 ENSG00000243485
strAD1.1 strAD1.1.1 ENST00000469289 ENSG00000243485
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just:

```
< file cut -sd '"' -f2,4,8,10 | tr '"' ' '
```

That is consider the input as a list of `"`-separated columns and extracting the 2<sup>nd</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup>, 8<sup>th</sup> and 10<sup>th</sup> columns.

With GNU `cut`, you can replace the `| tr '"' ' '` with `--output-delimiter=' '`.

That makes the assumption that `"` characters don't appear elsewhere in the lines, that those `gene_id`, `transcript_id`... attributes always appear and always in that order.

As noted by Kusalananda, that's not the case in your sample where it should be `2,4,6,8` for the first line and `2,4,8,10` for the others.

To do a more expressive matching: that only the 9<sup>th</sup> tab-delimited column should be considered and that the correct attribute names be found, you could resort to regular expressions like with:

```
< file pcregrep -o1 -o2 -o3 -o4 --om-separator=' ' '(?x)
  ^(?:[^\t]*+\t){8}(?=[^\t]*? \b gene_id       \ +"([^"\t]*)")
                   (?=[^\t]*? \b transcript_id \ +"([^"\t]*)")
                   (?=[^\t]*? \b reference_id  \ +"([^"\t]*)")
                   (?=[^\t]*? \b ref_gene_id   \ +"([^"\t]*)")'
```

If you don't have `pcregrep` or too old a version to support `-o1...`, you can use `perl` instead:

```
< file perl -lne 'print "$1 $2 $3 $4" if m{
  ^(?:[^\t]*+\t){8}(?=[^\t]*? \b gene_id       \ +"([^"\t]*)")
                   (?=[^\t]*? \b transcript_id \ +"([^"\t]*)")
                   (?=[^\t]*? \b reference_id  \ +"([^"\t]*)")
                   (?=[^\t]*? \b ref_gene_id   \ +"([^"\t]*)")}x'
```

That regexp first matches the first 8 fields (`(?:[^\t]*+\t){8}`) and following that, we have 4 look-ahead expressions (`(?=...)`), so we're matching for those 8 fields provided what follows matches all 4 of the look-ahead expressions. Each look-ahead expression looks for one of the attributes and captures the value (in the `(...)` part). Those captured values are then available in `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4`.

So that allows attributes in any order.

Note that it could be fooled by things like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 gene_id "transcript_id " ...
```

While it would be possible to address it, it's probably not worth the effort as I don't expect it would be occurring in the input.

While you're at using `perl`, you could also do a more formal parsing of that 9<sup>th</sup> field. Something like:

```
< file perl -F'\t' -lane '
  my %field;
  while ($F[8] =~ /(\w+) +"(.*?)"/g) {$field{$1}=$2}
  if (%field) {
    print join " ", @field{
      qw(gene_id transcript_id reference_id ref_gene_id
    )}
  }'
```

(here, printing a line as long as at least one attribute is found (as opposed to all the requested attributes in the other approaches)).

Comment: Thanks for all responses. Both commands worked fine. but I prefer the first one.